# Error with scrolling custom table cells in a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hi I'm a newbie to iOS development I'm facing a problem regarding scrolling of custom cells in a tableview. My table view has around 7 cells but once I scroll the view after running I will be getting only first 5 cells like the below but even tough the rest of the cells are being displayed we can't completely scroll to have a look at those cell.

Here's my viewController.m code

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MobileTableCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSArray *tableData;
    NSArray *thumbnails;

}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Iphone 5s",@"Google Nexus 5", @"Samsung Galaxy S4",@"HTC one", @"LG G2", @"Moto X", @"Micromax Turbo", nil];

    thumbnails = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"iphone5.jpg",@"nexus5.png",@"galaxys4.jpg",@"htcone.jpg",@"lgg2.jpg",@"motox.png",@"micromaxcanvasturbo2.jpg", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MyMobileTableCell";

    MobileTableCell *cell = (MobileTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    //NSLog(@"%@",cell);
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MobileTableCell" owner:self options:Nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
//    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 78;
}
@end
```

Please lemme know where I have gone wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your cellForRowIndexPath code ?

Comment: @NANNAV Ya i have edited my question with cellForRowIndexPath code .

Comment: It would also help to see the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` code.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of what this looks like? Are you usings the TableViewController or are there other things in the UIView?

Comment: @Mikael Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post a screenshot :(

Comment: What is the @interface row of your .h file?

Comment: @Mikael here is interface of .h file.                       //@interface ViewController :  UIViewController  <UItableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a UIViewController to render the UITable because you have: `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UItableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource>`. Better to directly use the UITableViewController provided `@interface ViewController : UITableViewController`. If you have a valid reason for using a UIView then you need to set the delegate and dataSource to self:

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
```

You also need to make sure there isn't anything else that is scrollable on the `UIView` that makes the table view scroll out of the page like a `UIScrollView` or something like that. You can use auto layout to help keep your stuff in view.

Last point, your issue might be the result of a `UINavigationController` covering parts of the table. If you are using a `UIView` you need to add content margin to the `UITable` to make sure the navigationController does not hide rows.

Comment: thanks for the answer. My problem has got resolved to an certain extent. But the thing is in my app the UIView is scrollable and so is the TableView which is inside the UIViewController so now the issue is I can scroll my UIView and can see 4 cells of the TableView but if I want to see the next 3 cells I have to scroll the TableView. So my question is how can I see all my tableView cells only by scrolling only UIView.

Comment: Why are you using a UIView with a scroll bar? Why not UITableViewController?

Comment: I was just trying it, can't i make any changes to these UIView itself ?

Comment: You can but you are not using the right tools so it will break in many ways like not showing you some cells. It only takes a few minutes to switch to the correct controller and it will not only fix this issues a many others you have not yet found.